# Handle recurring payments with paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'am having troubles about how to handle the paypal recurrent payment system.

I followed every instruction in the website, but once i create the profile, paypal puts it in pending, making me doubt about the reliability of the service itself.

I tried to look over the internet but i didn't really get how this should work...

i made the first call with `SetExpressCheckout` in order to create the request, when the token is returned, i send the token to the paypal page, the user confirms the payment, then i call the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method to confirm the operation (passing `PAYERID` and `TOKEN` and setting the `AMT` value for the first payment and the `PROFILESTARTDATE` as now +1 month for the future payments)

Now when i try to read the response from the last call (or if i go to the buyer/seller paypal account) i see that the payment is in pending and i have to wait an undefined amount of time before this payment is activated.

Now the real question is: can i trust the fact that even if the payment is in pending, i'll receive the payment and so i can set set the user as member or i have to check and wait until the status is 'active' with the `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` method?

PS: i'm doing this in the sandbox version, maybe the official version is a bit faster and more reliable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Sandbox as in Live when you call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile you will also get the response in which it will give you the status of the profile (ActiveProfile  or PendingProfile). When the status is in Penidng it means that the system is in process of creating the recurring payment profile. You can then check your IPN messages for an update. It is normal but obviously if you notice that all the profiles you create get into Pending and never activate then there could be a bug but should not be the case. In here is the PayPal technical guide for this API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Actually i assign the membership when i perform the ```CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile``` call, putting a flag "inactive", when the IPN sends me the Active status, i'll set the memebership as active aswell. I think this is the best thing to do for me, i just hope that the delay before the payment moves from pending to active is not that much. Thanks btw